# Only first IF statement is working! All other IF not working

Tags: python, python-3.x

Code is working! No errors! and also first IF is working!
But other IF statements are not working.

I am trying to open a CSV file and export a JSON file. So I am going through all rows in the CSV file and append data.

The problem is the code is going through the first IF only. so as result only 1 object is getting updated. All other IF statements need to be executed! Which they wont!

```
def make_json(File1, jsonFilePath):
    data1 = []
    with open('1.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader: 
            data1.append(rows)
  
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
            if data1[0]["Shift Pattern"] == "DA7": 
                data1[0]["shiftHourStart"] = "07:00:00"
                data1[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "17:30:00"
                data1[0]["daysOfWeek"] = "[0,1,2,3]"
            if data1[0]["Shift Pattern"] == "DB7": 
                data1[0]["shiftHourStart"] = "07:00:00"
                data1[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "17:30:00"
                data1[0]["daysOfWeek"] = "[3,4,5,6]"
            if data1[0]["Shift Pattern"] == "NB30":  
                data1[0]["shiftHourStart"] = "18:30:00"
                data1[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "05:00:00"
                data1[0]["daysOfWeek"] = "[3,4,5,6]"
            if data1[0]["Shift Pattern"] == "S30":  
                data1[0]["shiftHourStart"] = "13:30:00"
                data1[0]["shiftHourEnd"] = "22:00:00"
                data1[0]["daysOfWeek"] = "[1,2,3,4,5]"

            jsonf.write(simplejson.dumps(data1, indent=4))
```

Comment: What do you want ti iterate on?

Comment: I want to check each row in the JSON file and if any of those IF conditions meets, add those info..but right now, the code only works for the first object! and it doesnt check the rest...

Comment: have you tried removing `elif` with `if`?

Comment: Yes. I tried to put IF for all of them..didnt work too

Comment: The code is invalid due to capitalisation and indentation, and doesn't include enough of the logic for anyone to diagnose.

Comment: There is no row in JSON file and you are not checking anything **from** JSON file. `If` condition is only supposed to meet for `data1`.

Comment: Sorry, I had to re-write my question..Please check again..Updated the code

Comment: You write `data1[0]` and you expect the code to do anything with other rows than the first one?

Comment: Each object has a shift pattern for each employee. I want to add two lines to each objects like start-end hours based on shift pattern

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to loop through the data1 list and check every object?
Then you are missing the loop:

```
def make_json(File1, jsonFilePath):
    data1 = []
    with open('1.csv', encoding='utf-8') as csvf:
        csvReader = csv.DictReader(csvf)
        for rows in csvReader: 
            data1.append(rows)
  
    with open(jsonFilePath, 'w', encoding='utf-8') as jsonf:
            for i in data1:
                if i["Shift Pattern"] == "DA7": 
                    i["shiftHourStart"] = "07:00:00"
                    i["shiftHourEnd"] = "17:30:00"
                    i["daysOfWeek"] = "[0,1,2,3]"
                if i["Shift Pattern"] == "DB7": 
                    i["shiftHourStart"] = "07:00:00"
                    i["shiftHourEnd"] = "17:30:00"
                    i["daysOfWeek"] = "[3,4,5,6]"
                if i["Shift Pattern"] == "NB30":  
                    i["shiftHourStart"] = "18:30:00"
                    i["shiftHourEnd"] = "05:00:00"
                    i["daysOfWeek"] = "[3,4,5,6]"
                if i["Shift Pattern"] == "S30":  
                    i["shiftHourStart"] = "13:30:00"
                    i["shiftHourEnd"] = "22:00:00"
                    i["daysOfWeek"] = "[1,2,3,4,5]"


            jsonf.write(simplejson.dumps(data1, indent=4))
```